# Iterate through customers on a 12-months-rolling-basis and check if a customer has not orderd in the past 12 months

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aff2b41a97d2cac933c56049b0752be4)**

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date DATE,
    customer VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO customers
(order_date, customer)
VALUES 
('2020-03-10', 'user_01'),
('2020-03-18', 'user_02'),
('2020-03-26', 'user_03'),

('2020-04-12', 'user_04'),
('2020-04-19', 'user_05'),
('2020-04-23', 'user_06'),


('2021-03-09', 'user_01'),
('2021-03-17', 'user_07'),

('2021-04-03', 'user_02'),
('2021-04-18', 'user_05'),
('2021-04-20', 'user_08');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
churn_date    |   customer   |
--------------|--------------|----
2021-03-18    |   user_02    |
2021-03-26    |   user_03    |
--------------|--------------|-----
2021-04-12    |   user_04    |
2021-04-23    |   user_06    |
```

---

I want to **iterate** through the customers on a **12-months-rolling-basis** and **check for each months** if the last order from the customer has been placed 12 months ago.

For example: 
`user_02` should appear in the results of `March` but should not appear in the results of `April`. 
 In the view of `March` the last order happened 12 months ago on `2020-03-18`. 
In the view of `April` the last order happened on `2021-04-03`.

---

For a single month I am able to to this with this query:

```
SELECT
(c1.order_date + interval '12 month')::date as churn_date,
c1.customer
FROM customers c1
WHERE c1.order_date BETWEEN '2020-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-03-31 23:59:59'
    
AND NOT EXISTS
    
   (SELECT
    c2.customer
    FROM customers c2
    WHERE c2.order_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-03-31 23:59:59'
    AND c2.customer = c1.customer)

ORDER BY 1,2;
```

---

However, I have to run this query for each month seperatly.

Therefore, I am wondering if there is an iterating solution that goes through multiple months at once and gives me the expected result?

Comment: I remember this question as if it was asked before ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the previous query with a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT gs.month, c.customer, MAX(c.order_date + interval '12 month')::date as churn_date
FROM customers c CROSS JOIN
     GENERATE_SERIES('2021-03-01'::date, '2021-04-01'::date, interval '1 month') gs(month)
WHERE c.order_date < gs.month + interval '1 month'
GROUP BY gs.month, c.customer
HAVING DATE_TRUNC('month', MAX(c.order_date)) = DATE_TRUNC('month', gs.month) - interval '12 month';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=89fe6adce1a295c5797c36133c6d545a) is a db<>fiddle.