# Iterating through generated series on a rolling 12-months-basis in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=001ee4ed627455c662138458642078b0)**

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date DATE,
    customer VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO customers
(order_date, customer)
VALUES 
('2020-03-10', 'user_01'),
('2020-03-18', 'user_02'),
('2020-03-26', 'user_03'),

('2020-04-12', 'user_04'),
('2020-04-19', 'user_05'),
('2020-04-23', 'user_06'),


('2021-03-09', 'user_01'),
('2021-03-17', 'user_07'),

('2021-04-03', 'user_02'),
('2021-04-18', 'user_05'),
('2021-04-20', 'user_08');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
churn_date    |   customer   |
--------------|--------------|----
2021-03-18    |   user_02    |
2021-03-26    |   user_03    |
--------------|--------------|-----
2021-04-12    |   user_04    |
2021-04-23    |   user_06    |
```

---

I want to **iterate** through the customers on a **12-months-rolling-basis** and **check for each months** if the last order from the customer has been placed 12 months ago.

For example: 
`user_02` should appear in the results of `March` but should not appear in the results of `April`. 
 In the view of `March` the last order happened 12 months ago on `2020-03-18`. 
In the view of `April` the last order happened on `2021-04-03`.

---

In `postgresSQL` I am able to achieve this with the solution from [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67659898/iterate-through-customers-on-a-12-months-rolling-basis-and-check-if-a-customer-h):

```
SELECT 
gs.month AS month, 
c.customer AS customer, 
MAX(c.order_date + interval '12 month')::date as churn_date
FROM customers c 

    CROSS JOIN
    GENERATE_SERIES('2021-03-01'::date, '2021-04-01'::date, interval '1 month') AS gs(month)

WHERE c.order_date < gs.month + interval '1 month'
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING DATE_TRUNC('month', MAX(c.order_date)) = DATE_TRUNC('month', gs.month) - interval '12 month';
```

---

However, in `amazon-redshift` I get an error that the `GENERATE_SERIES` function does not exist. 
How do I have to modify the query to also make it work in `amazon-redshift`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Redshift, you need to explicitly define the table.  One method is in-line:

```
SELECT gs.month AS month, c.customer AS customer, 
       MAX(c.order_date + interval '12 month')::date as churn_date
FROM customers c CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT '2021-03-01'::date as month UNION ALL
      SELECT '2021-04-01'::date as month UNION ALL
      . . .
     ) gs
WHERE c.order_date < gs.month + interval '1 month'
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING DATE_TRUNC('month', MAX(c.order_date)) = DATE_TRUNC('month', gs.month) - interval '12 month';
```

You can play other tricks -- for instance, if you have a calendar table or numbers table or really any table with 12 rows:

```
FROM customers c CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT (date + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER () - 1) * INTERVAL '1 MONTH') as month 
      FROM (SELECT '2012-03-01'::date as date
            FROM <any table with 12 rows>
            LIMIT 12
           ) gs
      LIMIT 12
     ) gs
```